# Using Bitcore API for Escrow

Tags: transactions, node.js, bitcore

Has anyone experience using the [Bitcore](http://bitcore.io/guide/) API for Escrow purposes with node.js?

I assume, you'd need to create a new a address, then somehow create a new transaction using the newly created address, the probe that address for it's balance until its fulfilled.  I've had a look over the docs, but couldn't find anything.  Currently you can run bitcoind on a server and connect to this using RPC, but I'd like to try using Bitcore instead but achieve the same result.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question!

I'd take a look at [multi-sig construction in Bitcore](http://bitcore.io/guide/#Create_a_Multisig_Address), and pair this with [bitcore-wallet-service](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-wallet-service).  Some combination of these two items, with an agent to act as a signatory for a third key, would build a powerful escrow service in very short order.